# Highcharts: Show x-axis labels ony for years ending in zero (1950, 1960, 1970, ...)

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create a column chart with data from 1947 to 2012.  Is there a way to get the x-axis to display labels only when the years end with a zero?

So the chart would start with data for 1947, but the first x-axis labels would be "1950, 1960, 1970, ..."  I.e., blank axis labels for 1947, 1948, 1949, 1951, 1952 ...

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1.) specify your own ticks at the 10 year marks:

```
tickPositions: [Date.UTC(1950, 0, 1),Date.UTC(1960, 0, 1),Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1),...]
```

For this to work you'll also need to specify a custom formatter:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
     }
 }
```

2.) let Highcharts create the ticks and then 'discard' the ones that don't start a decade

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        var strVal = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
        if (strVal.endsWith('0')){
           return strVal;
         } else {
           return "";
         }
     }
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46ey7/1/) demonstrating both approaches.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I need, but I am sorry that I forgot to mention that the x-axis has been done with "Categories", not actual datetime values.
I thought I could change the "discard" approach to just use:
` var strVal = this.value; `
but that doesn't work.  Is there a way to check for "ends with zero" when the x-axis values are from categories like 
` categories: ["1947","1948","1949","1950", ... `

Comment: Just taking the value from the x-axis categories and checking it for ends with zero. Would this work?
  
`var strVal = this.value;`
 
`if (strVal.endsWith('0'))`

Comment: @user3692703, Yes, that would work, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZk52/

Comment: I would still recommend using a datetime axis and the original answer's method. Categories for dates create more problems than they solve.